# Formatting misunderstanding\

Tags: formatting

I have the following latex script:

```
\newtheorem*{BellOpV}{Definition}
\begin{BellOpV}
$V^{\pi}$ is defined as $T^{\pi}:\mathbb{R}^{|S|} \to \mathbb{R}^{|S|}$. It maps value functions to value functions.

$$(T^{\pi}V^{\pi})(s) = \sum_{a \in A} \pi(a|s) \left[ R(s,a) + \gamma \sum_{s' \in S} P(s' | s,a) V^{\pi}(s') \right]$$
\end{BellOpV}

The \emph{Bellman Operator for $V^{\pi}$} defined before has the following properties:

\begin{enumerate}
\item[]{$V^{\pi}$ is a \emph{fixed point} for $V^{\pi}$ that means that $T^{\pi}V^{\pi} = V^{\pi}$}
\item[]{$T^{\pi}$ is linear}
\item[]{if $0<\gamma<1$ then $T^{\pi}$ is a \emph{maximum-norm contraction}}
\end{enumerate}
```

The output of my code is the following:

[image: The output of my latex fragment]

My question is why from "The Bellman Operator ..." is all shifted on the right? Seems it is part of the definition, which is unwanted. How can I fix this?

Comment: You are using items without labels. `\item[]`. You have text, displayed math, another paragraph and a list of items. You should put a period to end the math. If you don't want another paragraph after it, just remove the blank line after the math. Also, don't use double dollar, use `\[ \]`.

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) It would be helpful if you provided a full minimal working example starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of code snippets. But apart from that, after the definition a new paragraph is issued. I think [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176027/82917) covers your case. Or simply add `\noindent` after the definition environment.

Comment: Since it is after `\end{BellOpV}` it is not part of definition. Also, note that it is not italicized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code may be improved in several ways, listed here in no particular order:

- Don't use `$$` to initiate and terminate displaymath mode in a LaTeX  document. Instead, use `\[` and `\]`. See the posting [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) for an in-depth discussion of this matter.
- Use `\colon` instead of `:` in definition.
- Use an `itemize` environment instead of an `enumerate` environment, and terminate each sentence with a period (dot, full stop); after all, they *are* full English-language sentences.
- Use `\mid` instead of `|` to denote the conditioning events.
- Typographically speaking, the square brackets generated by `\left[` and `\right]` are too big. Use `\biggl[` and `\biggr]` instead.
- Finally, if you absolutely, positively must suppress the paragraph indentation for the paragraph that follows the defintion, simply prefix it with a `\noindent` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,  % for '\newtheorem*' macro
            amssymb} % for '\mathbb' macro
\newtheorem*{BellOpV}{Definition}
\begin{document}

\begin{BellOpV}
$V^{\pi}$ is defined as $T^{\pi}\colon\mathbb{R}^{|S|} \to \mathbb{R}^{|S|}$. It maps value functions to value functions.
\[
(T^{\pi}V^{\pi})(s) = \sum_{a\in A} \pi(\,a\mid s\,) 
\biggl[ R(s,a) + \gamma \sum_{s'\in S} P(\,s'\mid s,a\,) V^{\pi}(s') \biggr]
\]
\end{BellOpV}

\noindent  % <--- are you sure you really want this?
The \emph{Bellman Operator} for $V^{\pi}$ defined before has the following properties:
\begin{itemize}
\item $V^{\pi}$ is a \emph{fixed point} for $V^{\pi}$, i.e.,  $T^{\pi}V^{\pi} = V^{\pi}$.
\item $T^{\pi}$ is linear.
\item If $0<\gamma<1$ then $T^{\pi}$ is a \emph{maximum-norm contraction}.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've hit the vote limit :( But this is a fantastic answer

Comment: @Au101 -- Many thanks, from one Star Wars and Harry Potter afficionado to another! :-)

Comment: Thanks very much for all your suggestions. Probably you all have a reason to say that it is a "wired" choice to put \noindent, but actually I think that without it the layout is very very ugly. By the way thanks to all of your suggestion again.

Comment: "Use `\colon` instead of `:`  [to separate the function name from the domain]"—this is definitely stylistic; as I'm sure you know, many (most?) authors indeed choose to use the more widely spaced version.

Comment: @wchargin - I'm afraid I have no firm basis for evaluating your claim about many/most(?) authors *choosing* to use `:` rather than `\colon`. If you have access to the TeXbook, do check out -- in chapter 16, "Typing Math Formulas" -- the material at the bottom of p. 133 and the top of p. 134. In particular, DEK wrote "If you want the `:` character to be treated as a punctuation mark instead of as a relation, just call it `\colon`."

Comment: Here you are, have a +1 :) Yes I was pleased to see your handle over on SF&F - nice answer on the 'Is Voldemort a liar?' question :)

Answer (score 3):

The phrase “Bellman Operator” *is* part of the definition! It *must* appear in it, but earlier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
The \emph{Bellman Operator for $V^{\pi}$} is defined as 
$T^{\pi}\colon\mathbb{R}^{|S|} \to \mathbb{R}^{|S|}$ by
\[
(T^{\pi}V^{\pi})(s) = 
\sum_{a \in A} \pi(a|s) \Bigl[ 
  R(s,a) + \gamma \sum_{s' \in S} P(s' \mid s,a) V^{\pi}(s')
\Bigr]
\]
It maps value functions to value functions.
\end{definition}

The Bellman operator for $V^{\pi}$ defined above has the following properties:
\begin{itemize}
\item $V^{\pi}$ is a \emph{fixed point} for $V^{\pi}$, which means 
      that $T^{\pi}V^{\pi} = V^{\pi}$;
\item $T^{\pi}$ is linear;
\item if $0<\gamma<1$ then $T^{\pi}$ is a \emph{maximum-norm contraction}.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

You may not want the line `\theoremstyle{definition}` before defining the `definition` environment; in this case the text will be italicized, except for the argument of `\emph` which would be in upright type. Usually definitions are typeset in upright type and only the defined term is in italics.

Points to note:

1. Never leave a blank line before a display
2. Think twice before leaving a blank line after a display, which means starting a new paragraph
3. Never use `$$`
4. The clause “It maps…” should go after the definition
5. The text about the properties is a new paragraph, so it should be indented
6. There's absolutely no need to use `\newtheorem` in front of every such environment
7. The `enumerate` or `itemize` environment should not have a blank line in front of it, because it's introduced by a clause
8. It's “which means”, not “that means”

Here's the rendering.

[image]

If you feel that `\mid` leaves too wide a space around the `|`, at least use `\,|\,` (and better define a macro).

By the way, I can't make sense of such a definition; please, check the part `$V^{\pi}$ is a \emph{fixed point} for $V^{\pi}$`, because it doesn't seem to mean anything sensible.

Comment: Good to know that you have some misgivings about the *contents* as well. I had the exact same misgivings but -- not being a mathematician myself (though I'm quite familiar with Bellman's equation and contraction mappings...) -- chose to constrain my answer to the the purely typographic issues... E.g, I'm pretty sure the sentence in the first `\item` should read "`$V^{\pi}$ is a \emph{fixed point} for $T^{\pi}$`".

Comment: Shouldn't there be period/full stop after the display equation?

Comment: using `amsthm`, it's assumed that any theorem-class environment ends with a paragraph break, so the next line of text is indented.  other theorem packages may differ.

Answer (score 1):

This is paragraph indentation. Just remove the blank line between `\end{BellOpV}` and `The \emph{Bellman Operator for $V^{\pi}$}...`.

Comment aside: never use `$$ ... $$` with LaTeX. This is plain TeX syntax and  yields bad spacing. Use `\[ ... \]` instead.

Comment: Removing the blank line won't work. The end of the definition issues a new paragraph by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in the following way:

```
\newtheorem{BellOpV}{Definition}
\AfterEndEnvironment{BellOpV}{\noindent\ignorespaces}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want the line below it always non indented? If it is a new paragraph, it should be indented!

Comment: @Sigur: That is debatable, as there is a vertical skip.

Comment: Would this even work in the OPs case because of the blank line before `The... `?